# Problems with Photos App under El Capitan

Tags: macos, photos, trash, slideshow

I have 2 problems.  First, I cannot find the trash icon anywhere (nor the "recent" flag.  Second, I cannot find the setting for adding titles to photographs in a slideshow.  It all worked in iPhoto but not any more

Comment: Questions should be limited to one specific question.  Consider rewriting the question or ask a separate one.

Answer (score 1):

Your trash is stored in `/.Trashes/`. Not sure if it's related to the new trash options in El Capitan, including permanent delete.